# What is currently known as the thinnest combination of material to hold 1 atm in space?

Tags: spacesuits, engineering, vacuum

What is currently known as the thinnest combination of material to hold 1 atm in space?

Note: must define what the composing materials are.

Comment: You can ignore micrometeors

Comment: Ignore debris in LEO as well? It's best to explain things like that in the question itself since sometimes people don't read the comments.

Comment: Since the question is tagged [spacesuits], are we to assume that you want answers limited to that?

Comment: A spacesuit with a pressure of 1 bar in vacuum is useless anyway. The poor astronaut would not be able to move his arms and legs against the forces resulting from the high pressure. Spacesuits are used with a much lower pressure, about 0.3 bar.

Comment: @DrSheldon No you do not need to constrain to suit material, I was originally thinking fabric but what I ultimately care about is the tensile strength needed to contain 1 atm with negligible loss of atmosphere. Abrasion and UV resistance would be nice to consider as well.

Comment: The necessary material thickness is lower for a forearm than for a tigh or the torso. The force caused by pressure in cylndrical suit part is proportional to the diameter. You should edit the question to include the word spacesuit. Reading wikipedia for operating pressures of different spacesuits is recommended.

Comment: @Uwe how exactly does pressure result in a "suit force"?

Comment: The size and shape are important. A glass microballoon has a wall thickness in the tens of nanometers and would have no trouble holding 1 atm. Not a suitable material for spacesuits though.